# PHP Adding objects to array from a txt file

Tags: php, arrays, file, include, load

I'm trying to add IP addresses to an array but i can't get it to work correctly
Can someone see what mistake i'm making or recommend another solution?

```
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$include = include "ip.txt";

$array = array($include);

if (in_array($ipaddress, $array)){
    echo "in array";
}
else {echo "error";}
```

this is what the ip.txt file looks like (it doesn't matter that the file is "public"):

```
'IP1', 'IP2', 'IP3', 'IP4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a few things wrong, but this should work for you:

```
<?php

    $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $include = file_get_contents("ip.txt");


    $array = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", $include));

    if (in_array($ipAddress, $array)) {
        echo "in array";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

?>
```

1. You have to use `file_get_contents()`, because include will first just include the file, so this plain text is in the php code and second it returns only `true` or `false`! For more information see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

And a quote from there:

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1.

2. You have to explode the string from the file and remove the single quotes to get the IP's in an array

3. PHP variables are case Sensitive, so `$ipAddress` and `$ipaddress` are 2 different variables! For more information see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

And also a quote from there:

> The variable name is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

`include` will try to run the file as a PHP program.

Instead, use `file_get_contents()`:

```
$include = file_get_contents('ip.txt');
$array = explode(', ', $include);

if (in_array("'$ipaddress'", $array)){
    echo "in array";
}
```

Since the IP addresses are surrounded with `'`, add it to the needle part in `in_array()` as well.

Easier would be to have the IP addresses each on one line. Then you can use `file()` which returns an array with the lines of the file.